# How to properly insert a variable into a json key in python

Tags: python, json, api, key, keyerror

I don't know how to properly enter a variable into a json key. I end up getting errors on the key directly afterward. The variable I want to enter is right after ["members"] where it says str(uuids[count]).

```
import requests
import json

uuids = []
count = 0
catacombs = []

data = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&id=5f1654598ea8c918612a6a43").json()
for guild in data["guild"]["members"]:
    uuids.append(guild["uuid"])

for guild in data["guild"]["members"]:
    data = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/profile?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&profile=" + str(uuids[count])).json()
    catacombs.append(data["profile"]["members"][str(uuids[count])]["dungeons"]["dungeon_types"]["catacombs"]["experience"])
    count += 1
    print(catacombs)
```

Any help at all is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `"dungeons"`? I didn't find it in json.

Comment: I can't add a picture but I would advise closing a lot of the tabs in the members tab. It is there though.

Comment: Check my answer.Tell me if there are any problems,

Comment: If my answer helped, just accept it by checking the mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's seems that the key `dungeons` didn't exist in some of the json.(And the experience, too).You could try `dict.get` and then to check whether it exists,

Also, you could use `zip` to iterate both the `uuids` and `data["guild"]["members"]` without use a index to count them.Code below:

```
import requests

uuids = []
catacombs = []

data = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&id=5f1654598ea8c918612a6a43").json()
for guild in data["guild"]["members"]:
    uuids.append(guild["uuid"])

for guild, uuid in zip(data["guild"]["members"], uuids):
    data = requests.get("https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/profile?key=42d64fe9-677c-433b-9460-f0177e0b9ded&profile=" + uuid).json()
    if data["profile"] is None:
        print(uuid, ": the profile is None")
        continue
    dungeons = data["profile"]["members"][uuid].get("dungeons")
    if dungeons is not None:
        experience = dungeons["dungeon_types"]["catacombs"].get("experience")
        if experience is not None:
            print(uuid, ":", experience)
            catacombs.append(experience)
        else:
            print(uuid, ": has dungeons but don't have experience ")
    else:
        print(uuid, ": no dungeons.")

print(catacombs)
```

And this gave me:

```
0baac74f903143e49d24015d8bc3a733 : no dungeons.
031c3178bfd04099b34301185d1182f3 : no dungeons.
c1558354fe2a48dabfa47cbce58cbe14 : no dungeons.
b4a5d02f35064dda9d84b58b238d0b62 : 526339.6999999998
69eda71c66ab4020ac394ba71dc84277 : no dungeons.
6cf3bb8096d048aca54ae52b987b0359 : 90720.06666666668
be3230d820b74a44a34854936499bb23 : 152437.7166666667
24002c0cce6343f2b0a8c090719da59d : 20386.716666666656

....

[526339.6999999998, 90720.06666666668, 152437.7166666667, 20386.716666666656 .... ]
```

Comment: Sorry, for not being able to respond earlier. I just wanted to say thanks a lot for the help. I will adjust it as necessary, I just need to learn some of these terms. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, after a second try, I noticed that once the program got onto this specific "uuid",  11f3261b8afe4b72809a2e8c1122b993, it gave me a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Any ideas why this occurs some of the time, but not all of the time.

Comment: @Igris That seems the json is not usual.I try to send request to this page.That's gave me: `{'success': True, 'profile': None}`.